# postfix unknown user info

Tags: debian, postfix

I tried again to make a mailserver on debian now.

My `main.cf` looks like this:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory                 = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file              = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file               = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls                    = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database  = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions         = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname                       = debian.www.example.com
alias_maps                       = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database                   = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin                         = /etc/mailname
mydestination                    = example.com, debian.www.example.com, localhost.www.example.com, localhost
relayhost                        = 
mynetworks                       = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command                  = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit               = 0
recipient_delimiter              = +
inet_interfaces                  = all

# virtual_domains 

virtual_mailbox_domains          = example1.com example2.com 
virtual_mailbox_base             = /var/mail/vhosts 
virtual_mailbox_maps             = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox 
virtual_minimum_uid              = 100 
virtual_uid_maps                 = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps                 = static:5000
virtual_alias_maps               = hash://etc/postfix/virtual
```

`/etc/postfix/virtual` looks like this:

```
postmaster@example.com   postmaster
postmaster@example1.com  postmaster
```

`/etc/postfix/vmailboxes` looks like this:

```
info@example.com     example.com/info 
sales@example1.com   example1.com/info
```

I restarted postfix with systemctl restart postfix after doing `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual` and `postmap /etc/postfix/vmailboxes`.

But still the error message that postfix cannot find the user info

`/var/mail` has as owner 5000:5000.

What might be the problem?

Edit1 : Mail.log of a single mail :

```
Apr 29 00:20:55 debian postfix/pickup[1375]: 994512F8: uid=0 from=<root>
Apr 29 00:20:55 debian postfix/cleanup[1424]: 994512F8: message-id=<20170428222055.994512F8@debian.www.example.com>
Apr 29 00:20:55 debian postfix/qmgr[1376]: 994512F8: from=<root@example.com>, size=430, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 29 00:20:55 debian postfix/local[1426]: 994512F8: to=<info@example.com>, relay=local, delay=0.04, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "info")
Apr 29 00:20:55 debian postfix/cleanup[1424]: A02AE407: message-id=<20170428222055.A02AE407@debian.www.example.com>
Apr 29 00:20:55 debian postfix/qmgr[1376]: A02AE407: from=<>, size=2171, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 29 00:20:55 debian postfix/bounce[1427]: 994512F8: sender non-delivery notification: A02AE407
Apr 29 00:20:55 debian postfix/qmgr[1376]: 994512F8: removed
Apr 29 00:20:55 debian postfix/local[1426]: A02AE407: to=<roelof@example.com>, orig_to=<root@example.com>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
Apr 29 00:20:55 debian postfix/qmgr[1376]: A02AE407: removed
Apr 29 00:50:44 debian postfix/qmgr[1376]: A53F3F9: from=<root@example.com>, size=431, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 29 00:50:44 debian postfix/virtual[1939]: A53F3F9: to=<info@example1.com>, relay=virtual, delay=4604, delays=4604/0.02/0/0.02, dsn=4.2.0, status=deferred (delivery failed to mailbox /var/mail/vhosts/example1.com/info: unable to create lock file /var/mail/vhosts/example1.com/info.lock: No such file or directory)
```

Edit 2: error mail to postmaster

```
Content-Description: Delivery report
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; debian.www.example.com
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 994512F8
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; root@example.com
Arrival-Date: Sat, 29 Apr 2017 00:20:55 +0200 (CEST)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; info@example.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; unknown user: "info"

--994512F8.1493418055/debian.www.example.com
Content-Description: Undelivered Message
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Return-Path: <root@example.com>
Received: by debian.www.example.com (Postfix, from userid 0)
    id 994512F8; Sat, 29 Apr 2017 00:20:55 +0200 (CEST)
Date: Sat, 29 Apr 2017 00:20:55 +0200
To: info@example.com
Subject: test
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.5 6/20/10
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Message-Id: <20170428222055.994512F8@debian.www.example.com>
From: root@example.com (root)

test

--994512F8.1493418055/debian.www.example.com--
```

Comment: What *exactly* do your mail logs say? Can you provide a complete log excerpt for a single SMTP transaction?

Comment: Added a mail log of 1 mail and the error mail that the postmaster is getting

Comment: `unable to create lock file /var/mail/vhosts/example1.com/info.lock: No such file or directory` So does the directory /var/mail/vhosts/example1.com exist, with correct permissions?

Comment: I thought that postfix would make that one. I have a directory /var/mail where 5000:5000 is the owner.

Comment: I checked and the directory var/mail has the following permissions : drwxrw_d